# Why doesn't gridview pagination work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

Why doens't my `asp.net` `GridView` pagination work?

It works for few pages but not always. When I click 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc, it works for the first click but not all, why?

```
protected void grdViewCases_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdViewCases.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    ShowCases(txtBoxCaseNo.Text);
}

public DataTable ShowCases(string CaseNo) 
{
    short UserID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UserID"]);
    DataTable dt = MngCases.SelectCasesByCaseNo(CaseNo.Trim(), UserID);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        grdViewCases.DataSource = dt;
        grdViewCases.DataBind();
        grdViewCases.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        grdViewCases.EmptyDataText = "No Record Found";
        grdViewCases.DataBind();
        grdViewCases.Visible = true;
    }

    return dt;
}
```

I have debugged it but throws no exception.

Comment: any browser console errors?

Comment: @lem2802 no not at all

Comment: just to be sure, try to set to null the DataSource before update it

Comment: @lem2802 sorry didn't get you sir ?

Comment: every time you change the page, the grdViewCases_PageIndexChanging event is fired?

Comment: @MarlonVidal yes but doesn't turn page

Comment: it could be that you're rebinding and setting `grdViewCases.DataSource = dt`

Comment: also, why are you returning a DataTable type from `ShowCases` when you're not doing anything with it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grdViewCases.DataSource = null;

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    grdViewCases.DataSource = dt;
    grdViewCases.DataBind();
    grdViewCases.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    grdViewCases.EmptyDataText = "No Record Found";
    grdViewCases.DataBind();
    grdViewCases.Visible = true;
}
```